# What is the difference between google.cloud.pubsub_v1 and google.cloud.pubsub?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-python, google-python-api

I see both used in different documentation from Google:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub
```

Is found in:

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/pubsub
- https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/

Whereas

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
```

Is find in:

- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/pubsub/cloud-client/subscriber.py
- https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull

Comment: The link is no longer valid.`https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/pubsub`. 
And also i don't see usage of approach #1 of from google.cloud import pubsub any where.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The google.cloud.pubsub library is designed to be make it easy to get the best performance out of a Cloud Pub/Sub publisher and subscriber. It has more advanced features such as message batching, asynchronous message delivery, and automatic ack deadline extension for messages not yet acknowledged by a subscriber. The API is different from the underlying Cloud Pub/Sub service API. For example, this library does not expose the `pull` method directly; messages are instead delivered to a callback passed into the [subscriber](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/subscriber/api/client.html#google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber.client.Client.subscribe)'s `open` method.

The google.cloud.pubsub_v1 library exposes the [underlying API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rpc/google.pubsub.v1) directly. It can be useful in specific cases where this level of control is necessary, e.g., when a synchronous subscriber is required in order to make requests in response to synchronous actions from a downstream dependency.

When possible, it is best to use the google.cloud.pubsub library.

Comment: Hi, Just to confirm, is this still valid?

I did `pip install google-cloud-pubsub` just now and in virtualenv all it seems to create folders /site-packages/google/cloud/`pubsub_v1`/* ... 

doing `pip install google-cloud-pubsub_v1` returns:
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-cloud-pubsub_v1 ...

Comment: also, it seems the Client Library (`pubsub_v1`) no longer suppose REST API, it only supports gRPC based API any longer...

Thanks!

Comment: @VibhorJain The package to install is `google-cloud-pubsub` which uses the name spaces `google` and `google.cloud` and installs to those pubsub_v1 directories as you found. The name of the directory is not important. Google are moving all the client libraries to gRPC, as mentioned https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained "We plan to upgrade as many Cloud Client Libraries as possible to gRPC" and why not? protocol buffers over http/2 is faster. Ideally, don't write your own REST client code, let the client library handle low level details.

Comment: Looks like _there is no difference_ pubsub appears to be just importing from pubsub_v1 see https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub.py AND https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/__init__.py

i.e. the pubsub SubcriberClient() class IS pubsub_v1.subscriber.client

The `pull` method was blacklisted in the pubsub_v1 client and consequently in pubsub client. That method was also re-exposed https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/commit/416fbee0cad89337120f123cbf680e27d3b32a5c

Comment: I think this answer is still correct though, because there are some things not exposed, like futures, and it does have some tricky decorators, blacklisting  and add method mechanisms to control the interface. It also makes heavy use of `__all__` to control exactly what is imported.

Comment: @Davos I had posted  a question earlier here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659169/is-google-cloud-pubsub-v1-publisherclient-thread-safe ` does it impact the choice between pubsusb vs pubs_v1 ?

Comment: @Fadi no I think that question's answer is clear. This page explains the difference between the older `google api client libraries` vs the newer `google cloud client libraries`. The names are similar and it is confusing tbh. https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained