# Is google.cloud.pubsub_v1.PublisherClient Thread safe?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I am using google cloud PubSub and was wondering whether `google.cloud.pubsub_v1.PublisherClient` was thread safe. Do I need to pass a new instance of this object to each `threading.Thread` or is it safe to share the same instance across threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the client library you are using.

[This Python client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/pubsub/v1#appengine) is [not thread safe](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety) due to being built on top of the httplib2 library, which is not thread-safe. But, as the first link says, this is an old library. The [newer Python library for Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) is thread safe.

Other Google client libraries are "thread safe" too. [The .NET one](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/index.html), for example, was bult with the convention in mind that all static members should be thread-safe.

Comment: thx @Guillermo. I did install via the second link actually but there is some confusion about their python docs. There seems to be a google.cloud.pubsub_v1 and google.cloud.pubsub. I have been using pubs_v1 and can not really see much difference between the 2. any insights would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you point to the documentation pages that are confusing? As far as I know, `from google.cloud import pubsub` and `from google.cloud import pubsub_v1` are equivalent. The versionless import is just an alias to the latest API version, which is v1

Comment: sorry that was dumb! yes they are equivalent. one references from the other. thx for clarifying :)

Comment: @Fadi Don't worry! There's so much documentation from so many sources that is easy to get lost and have doubts. I'm glad I clarified the confusion.